# What is the value group of $ \Bbb{F}_q((t^{1/p^n}))$ ?(Detailed caluculation)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What is the value group of $ \Bbb{F}_q((t^{1/p^n}))$ ?(Detailed caluculation)

I'm not good at calculating value group, and my only tactics is to calculate the value of each element.
$｜t^{p^{1/n}}u｜＝1/p^n$×(integer), so the value group is $1/p^n \Bbb{Z}$ ?

Just result answer is not needed, I want to check the polite and accurate process of calculating valuation, thank you for your kind help.

Comment: What is the valuation/absolute value of $\sum_{m\ge -M} a_m t^{m/p^n}$ ? Note that it can be normalized in many different ways, you probably meant relatively to some valuation on $\Bbb{F}_q((t))$. And in $p$-adic number theory we prefer the additive discrete valuation $v$ not the multiplicative absolute value $|.|$.

Comment: Sorry for my typo, it is $1/p^M$×$ord_p(a_m)$. I may be not good at calculating extended valuation, not $ord_p$.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with $ord_p$ and with $1/p^M$. Note that $a_m\in \Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Maybe I 'm stuck there. Could you give me what is an extended value on $ \Bbb{F}_q((t^{1/p^n}))$ and why is that ?